# Angular: HttpClient import Error how do i solve this error

Tags: angular

I was creating a simple CRUD operation and in this when i was importing HttpClient Module at that time I Found error like

" ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:81:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/common/http) which declares HTTP Client has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update
if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy."

show what do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Replace HttpClient to HttpClientModule in app-module.ts